# Power Attack, Rage and Bite Attack together

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, rage, multiattack, unchained

We are looking at a

- Lvl4 Unchained Barbarian (BAB: +4, no multiple attacks yet)
- STR Bonus +3
- [Dwarven Longhammer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/longhammer-dwarven/)-esque weapon that does not have the [Reach](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/#wpn-quality-reach) Special Weapon Feature
- [Animal Fury Rage Power](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/animal-fury-ex/)
- [Power Attack Feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat/)

| Row | Full Attack | Raging | Power Attack | Attack Bonus | Damage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | No | No | +7 | 2d6 + 4 |
| 2 | No | No | Yes | +5 | 2d6 + 10 |
| 3 | No | Yes | No | +9 | 2d6 + 6 |
| 4 | No | Yes | Yes | +7 | 2d6 + 12 |
| 5 | Yes | Yes | No | +9 / +4 | 2d6 + 6 / 1d4 +3 |
| 6 | Yes | Yes | Yes | +7 / +2 | 2d6 + 12 / 1d4 +5 |

1. BAB+STR = Attack Bonus, STR x1.5 rounded down as Damage Bonus because of 2-handed weapon
2. Power Attack at BAB>=4 gets a -2 on Attack Bonus and +4 on Damage, x1.5 rounded down because of 2-handed weapon
3. Unchained Rage gives a flat +2 Attack Bonus and +2 Damage Bonus
4. Basically Row 2 and 3 added together
5. "If used as part of a full attack action, the bite attack is made at the barbarian’s full base attack bonus –5. [..] plus half the barbarian’s Strength modifier". Rage Bonus applies, because the Barbarian only has the bite attack if she is raging.
6. As Row 5, Power Attack's "This bonus to damage is halved (–50%) if you are making an attack with an off-hand weapon or secondary natural weapon." applies, because the Bite Attack is treated as secondary (?)

Is all of this correct? There seem to be so many Bonuses that have to be added right... The rows "Full Attack, but not raging" where omitted, because they are essential the same as rows 1. / 2.
What would the table look like at Level 6 with a BAB of +6/+1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your table is correct

All of the information in your table is correct based on the statistics provided.

### At level 6

All of your Attack Bonus column's current numbers increase by 2 (plus any Strength bonus you get). Add a second Weapon Attack that is

- +4 with no modifiers
- +2 with Power Attack
- +6 while Raging
- +4 with Power Attack and Rage

The damage for this attack is the same as your first attack (2d6+4, 2d6+10, etc), increased if your Strength has increased. Your Bite attack doesn't change other than its +2 to hit unless your Strength increased, in which case your even modifier would increase the damage to 1d4+2 and 1d4+4.

Comment: Bite Attack Damage: should be +1 (reduced rounded down STR Bonus because of secondary natural), [+2 (reduced Power Attack Bonus because of secondary natural)], +2 (Rage Bonus) = +3 / +5 without / with Power Attack?

Comment: Er I forgot you skipped full attack w/o Rage and Power Attack. No, you had it right then